# Redux-form handleSubmit: How to access store state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

**In a redux-form `handleSubmit` function, which makes an Ajax call, some properties from the Redux state are needed in the Ajax (e.g. user ID).**

This would be easy enough if I wanted to define `handleSubmit` in the form's component: Just call `mapStateToProps` to pass in whatever I need, and read it from `this.props` in my `handleSubmit`.

However, like a good React-Redux developer I write **separate view components and containers**, so my view components can be simple with little or no behavior. Therefore, I want to **define handleSubmit in my container**.

Again, simple - redux-form is set up to do that. Define an `onSubmit` in `mapDispatchToProps`, and the form will call it automatically.

Except, oh wait, in `mapDispatchToProps` there's no way to access redux state.

Okay, no problem, I'll just pass the props I need into `handleSubmit` along with the form values.

Hmm, wait, it is impossible to pass any data into `handleSubmit` using this mechanism! You get one parameter, `values`, and there's no way to add another parameter.

This leaves the following unattractive alternatives (of which I can verify that 1 and 2 work):

1 **Define a submit handler in the form component,** and from there call my own custom submit handler function passed in from mapDispatchToProps. This is okay, but requires my component to know some props from the redux state that aren't required to display the form. (This issue is not unique to redux-form.)

```
dumbSubmit(values)
{
  const { mySubmitHandler, user} = this.props;
  mySubmitHandler(values, user);
}

<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.dumbSubmit.bind(this)) }>
```

Or, more concisely, this can all be combined into an arrow function:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{mySubmitHandler(values, this.props.user);}
```

Then to make this handler completely agnostic, it could just pass the entire this.props back to the custom handler:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{mySubmitHandler(values, this.props);}
```

2 **Define onSubmit in mergeProps** instead of mapDispatchToProps, so it has access to stateProps. [Dan Abramov recommends against using mergeProps (for performance reasons)](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237#issuecomment-168818326), so this seems suboptimal.

```
  function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  const { user } = stateProps.authReducer;
  const { dispatch } = dispatchProps;
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...stateProps,
     onSubmit: (values) => {
       const { name, description } = values;
       const thing = new Thing(name, description, []);
       dispatch(createNewThing(thing, user.id));
     }
  }
```

3 **Copy the state properties into redux-form fields** which are not mapped to any input controls in the form component. This will ensure they are accessible in the `values` parameter passed back to `handleSubmit`. This seems like kind of a hack.

### There's got to be a better way!

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**After spending time refining this question, option #1 is actually pretty good**, in the final iteration (arrow function that passes all props back to the custom handler). It allows the component to be stateless and completely ignorant of any state that it doesn't consume. So I'm going to call that a reasonable answer. I would love to hear your better solutions!

---

Define a submit handler using an arrow function in the form component, and from there call my own custom submit handler function passed in from mapDispatchToProps.

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{mySubmitHandler(values, this.props.user);}
```

Then to make this handler completely agnostic, pass the entire this.props back to the custom handler:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{mySubmitHandler(values, this.props);}
```

If the Submit function only needs the values and the props that weren't part of the form, we can pass back just those props which the form doesn't use. In a stateless component, this might look like:

```
const Thing_Create = ({ fields: {name, description}, 
    error, 
    handleSubmit, 
    mySubmitHandler, 
    submitting, 
    onCancel, 
    ...otherprops}) => {
return (
<div>
  <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{
    mySubmitHandler(values, otherprops);}) }>
[rest of form definition would go here]
```

Comment: is it still the best way to do..?

Comment: good Q and A, it's like you read my mind. I wonder if there is a specific name for this kind of technique? is it an example of currying? you are essentially wrapping your binary function `mySubmitHandler` in another unary function ie, `fn (a) { fn(a, b) }`, which I think technically fits the definition. just curious

Comment: @sbeam This isn't currying, but it's close. Currying would be declaring a function `const add = x => y => x + y` whereas this is more like `const add = x => myAdder(x, y)`. I provided a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found is pretty similar to the first solution you came up with.

Take advantage of the fact that the `handleSubmit` prop passed by redux-form can take a function that will be used as the `onSubmit` prop, and use partial application to pass any other parameters you need to `onSubmit`.

Action creator:

```
function updateUser(id, { name, lastname }) { ... }
```

Suppose the component gets an `onUpdateUser` property that just passes the parameters straight to the action creator. And the component also gets `user`, an object with the `id` property that we want to pass to the action creator along with the values in the fields.

Component

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.onUpdateUser.bind(null, this.props.user.id))}>
```

This can easily be re-written for stateless functional components, can work for any amount of parameters as long as you place them on the left in the action creator, and it doesn't need any heavy lifting, just `bind`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by binding `this`.

**Somewhere in render()**

```
<MyCustomFormComponent onSubmit={handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

**The handleSumit**

```
  handleSubmit(fields) {
    this.props.onSubmit(fields); //this is properly bound, HURRAY :-)
  }
```

**MapDispatchToProps** *for good developers :-)*

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onSubmit: (fields) =>
    dispatch({type: auth.actionTypes.LOGIN, payload: auth.api.login(fields)})
});
```

Comment: This question was about accessing store state in mapDispatchToProps(). It looks like your example is just showing the "vanilla" case of how to use handleSubmit, where you just need to access data from the fields (without any additional data from the store). For that you can just follow the directions in the redux-form docs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually when I have access to thisOrg in handleSubmit, I can access store state in it, and can pass anything to MapDispatchToProps's onSubmit method. I have checked to get any state value (not just fields), and it was success. Sorry if I missed something or misunderstood your question. I am open to change/delete my answer, if its  wrong.

Comment: Well, the question is about whether it's possible to get store data in `mapDispatchToProps` **without passing it into the form component**, because it's data that the form doesn't need and has no business knowing. I can't tell without seeing your code, but it sounds like you are describing passing data into the form (maybe via `mapStateToProps`? you didn't say) and then passing it back out again in `handleSubmit`. Doing it that way is already covered in the accepted answer. If you're doing something different, you could post your code, if it adds info that hasn't been covered.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of [@stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37168/stone)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557000/2237813), but you can break down option 1 via functional programming:

```
const mySubmitHandler = props => values => { /* ...code here */ }

<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(mySubmitHandler(this.props)) }>
```

In this case, `mySubmitHandler` will return a function taking only one argument that has already closed over `this.props`, so there's no need to explicitly mention the `values` argument that `handleSubmit` is passing.

You could perform the currying of `mySubmitHandler` in a better and more readable way through [ramda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda).

```
import { curry } from 'ramda';

const mySubmitHandler = curry((props, values) => { /* ...code here */ });
```

You can go one step further by composing `handleSubmit` and `mySubmitHandler`

```
import { compose, curry } from 'ramda';

const handleSubmit = values => { /* ...code here */ };
const mySubmitHandler = curry((props, values) => { /* ...code here */ });
const onSubmit = compose(handleSubmit, mySubmitHandler);

<form onSubmit={ onSubmit(this.props) }>
```

Note that `onSubmit(this.props)` returns a function that takes one argument (`values`) and has closed over `this.props`, creating a function that has access to all the properties it needs!