# How to reference a prop when submitting redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have two models - contact and note. A note belongs to a contact.

I am trying to find a way to reference the contactId in the submit function.

I have passed contactId from a parent to the form:

```
// parent.js
<NoteNewForm contactId={contactId} onCancel={onCancelNewNoteClick}/>
```

In my form I want to use this in the `submit` function. I tried passing it as a param - i.e. `submit(contactId)` - but this does not work

```
const submit = (values, dispatch) => {
  var noteData = Object.assign({}, values)

  var primary = {
    type: "notes",
    attributes: noteData
  }

  // I want to use contactId instead of id: "1"
  var relationships = {
    contact: {
      data: {
        type: "contacts",
        id: "1"
      }
    }
  }

  var params = createFormattedParams(primary, relationships)
  dispatch(createNoteForContact(params))
}

export class NoteNewForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.getValidationState = this.getValidationState.bind(this)
  }

  getValidationState(isError = false, isTouched = false) {
    if (isError && isTouched) {
      return "error"
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {fields: {subject, details, date}, handleSubmit, onCancel, contactId} = this.props
    var extraProps = omit({...date}, 'value')
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={6} smPush={6}>
            <FormGroup controlId="date"
                       validationState={this.getValidationState(date.error, date.touched)}>
              <ControlLabel>Date</ControlLabel>
              <DateTimeField
                inputProps={extraProps}
                dateTime={date.value != "" ? date.value : moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
                format="YYYY-MM-DD" inputFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" mode="date"
                onChange={value => date.onChange(value)}
                maxDate={moment()}
              />
              {date.touched && date.error &&
              <HelpBlock>{date.error}</HelpBlock>
              }
              <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} sm={6} smPull={6}>
            <FormGroup controlId="subjectText"
                       validationState={this.getValidationState(subject.error, subject.touched)}>
              <ControlLabel>Subject</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl type="text" {...subject}/>
              {subject.touched && subject.error &&
              <HelpBlock>{subject.error}</HelpBlock>
              }
              {!subject.error && !subject.value &&
              <HelpBlock>Required</HelpBlock>
              }
              <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12}>
            <FormGroup controlId="detailsText"
                       validationState={this.getValidationState(details.error, details.touched)}>
              <ControlLabel>Details</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl type="text" {...details}/>
              {details.touched && details.error &&
              <HelpBlock>{details.error}</HelpBlock>
              }
              {!details.error && !details.value &&
              <HelpBlock>Required</HelpBlock>
              }
              <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br/>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <div className="pull-right">
              <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button type="submit" className="btn-accent">
                  Create
                </Button>
                <Button type="button" onClick={onCancel}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

NoteNewForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'NoteNewForm',
  fields: ['subject', 'details', 'date'],
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  validate
})(NoteNewForm)

export default NoteNewForm
```

I'm at a loss... Any ideas would be great.

## Update! Solved below

I used the suggestion and link from skypecakes and this is the working code:

```
// the submit function
const submit = (values, dispatch, contactId) => {
  var noteData = Object.assign({}, values)

  var primary = {
    type: "notes",
    attributes: noteData
  }

  var relationships = {
    contact: {
      data: {
        type: "contacts",
        id: contactId
      }
    }
  }

  var params = createFormattedParams(primary, relationships)
  dispatch(createNoteForContact(params))
}
```

In the form:

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((values, dispatch) => {submit(values, dispatch, contactId)})} noValidate
        autoComplete="off">
```

Comment: how 'handleSubmit' func looks like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux-form handleSubmit: How to access store state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539601/redux-form-handlesubmit-how-to-access-store-state)

Comment: I feel this method is a code smell. Forms should only have the responsibility to "collect data". In the above method the form also has the knowledge of how to "dispatch data". That is the responsibility of a thunk, saga, etc... Either collect the data via hidden form elements, or via a composed submit function in your  container component (wrapping your form). Forms should be dumb in the sense they are only connected to the redux-form state tree. That way they are more testable and have less responsibilities.

Comment: I completely agree, what we really want is for the handler that is defined outside the form to have access to any values it needs plus the input from the form. You can accomplish that by using mergeprops, but that has performance implications.  If you have a better solution I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is explored in depth in the following question:

[Redux-form handleSubmit: How to access store state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539601/redux-form-handlesubmit-how-to-access-store-state/37557000#37557000)

Short answer: You can create a custom submit handler or use mergeprops. Custom submit handler seems cleaner. See the answer for how to use the custom submit handler.

You define your custom submit handler in `mapDispatchToProps()`, then call it like this:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{mySubmitHandler(values, this.props.user);}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'll update answer with what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

in order to pass some value, you should use .bind(null, value)

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit.bind(null, contactId ))}
       noValidate autoComplete="off">
```

then in callback

```
const submit = (values, dispatch, contactId  ) => {
....
var relationships = {
    contact: {
      data: {
        type: "contacts",
        id: contactId,  //  <---------------------
      }
    }
  }
.....
```

Comment: I tried this and when i do `console.log(contactId)` in the submit function I get  the output of dispatch not contactId

Comment: Redux-form ignores what you pass to the handler and always passes (values, dispatch).

Answer (score 0):

**better still**

Why not have a hidden form field. Set its value through the `initialValues` prop of your form component. Then in the submit function you receive the values of all fields as a parameter (v6.x.x) only of course

**or**

The action creator that you pass into your form `sendFormData` that is called in your submit function can be wrapped / composed with the required data before it's even passed into the form. That way the form has no need or knowledge of the data. It just knows how to collect data and then send it. Single responsibility... E.g.

```
// Container component wrapping form: Let the code do the talking....

submitNote = (formValues) => {
  this.props.createNoteThunk(this.props.contactId, formValues);
}

render() {

    return (
        <YourForm submitNote={this.submitNote} />
    );
}
```

Comment: I had a similar thought too but the creator of `redux-form` has said on a few questions relating to hidden fields that this is a bit of an anti-pattern. Unfortunately, doesn't really explain the alternative in those questions. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I don't agree with that. :-) it's really not at all. IDs are inherently hidden fields and part of the forms data model. Otherwise another option, also proffered is now in the answer above

Comment: Yeah fair enough, just re-iterating what he has said to other Qs. I'm gonna give a few of these answers a go and see how I get on. Thanks for taking the time to pitch one/two in

Comment: @patrick I added an example of a composed submit function , i really feel its the way to go.

Comment: I love the composed function idea. Nice way to keep the form completely independent of data it doesn't need. I'll try it out.

Comment: Turns out you still need those props when you compose the function! So this approach still requires mergeProps. But if you set a property on the container (from **its** container, another level up the chain), you could use mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) and then get it from ownProps. I guess that's a little better, because it makes more sense for the higher-level component to access state props than the low-level form. Still seems overly complex. I'll add an example of this to my linked answer.